# CSS - element with fixed height and width - shrink when parent is smaller than element

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Is it possible to set the `height` and `width` of an element and have it shrink when the parent `height` is smaller than the child `height`?

I have a reusable icon button component and i want it to have a specific `height` and `width` as it is a square.
But when used inside an input element i want it to shrink so it will only use the available space/height of the input element.

Here is a little [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/1BIR1rkBk9) of it.

```css
svg {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<div class="bg-green-200 h-screen p-4 flex flex-col gap-4 items-start">
  <button class="inline-flex items-center border border-transparent justify-center rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-green-500 p-2 text-2xl max-h-16 h-full w-16 bg-white hover:bg-green-50 text-gray-400">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path></svg>
  </button>

  <div class="mt-1 rounded border-2 border-transparent focus-within:ring-green-500 focus-within:border-green-500 bg-white flex items-center gap-1 p-4 text-lg h-16">
    <input id="downshift-1-input" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="downshift-1-menu" aria-labelledby="downshift-1-label" autocomplete="off" class="block w-full focus:outline-none" value="" />
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center children:any-h-full h-full text-2xl">
      <div class="flex items-center gap-1 text-gray-400">
        <button class="inline-flex items-center border border-transparent justify-center rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-green-500 p-2 text-2xl max-h-16 h-full w-16 bg-white hover:bg-green-50 text-gray-400">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path></svg></button
        ><span
          ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M8 9l4-4 4 4m0 6l-4 4-4-4"></path></svg
        ></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I managed to get it to work for the `height`, but now the `width` is the problem when i use it in the input element. I tried setting it with `max-width`, but didn't succeed and i'm a little stuck right now.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the input of Ala Mouhamed and silvenon i managed to get it to work by using `aspect-ratio` and a fixed height. When using it inside the input field i just pass `h-auto` to the icon button and override the fixed height. This way it will adjust to the height of the input -> [Tailwind Play Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RsaQJ47KFQ)

```css
svg {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<div class="bg-green-200 h-screen p-4 space-y-4">
  <button class="inline-flex items-center border border-transparent justify-center rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-green-500 p-2 text-2xl h-16 aspect-square bg-white hover:bg-green-50 text-gray-400">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path></svg>
  </button>

  <div class="mt-1 rounded border-2 border-transparent focus-within:ring-green-500 focus-within:border-green-500 bg-white flex items-center gap-1 p-4 text-lg h-16">
    <input id="downshift-1-input" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="downshift-1-menu" aria-labelledby="downshift-1-label" autocomplete="off" class="block w-full focus:outline-none" value="" />
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center children:any-h-full h-full text-2xl">
      <div class="flex items-center gap-1 text-gray-400">
        <button class="inline-flex items-center border border-transparent justify-center rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-green-500 p-2 text-2xl h-16 h-auto aspect-square bg-white hover:bg-green-50 text-gray-400">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path></svg></button
        ><span
          ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M8 9l4-4 4 4m0 6l-4 4-4-4"></path></svg
        ></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new css property "aspect-ratio", and set it to "1/1" , it will maintain proportional dimensions while the elements width or height changes depending on its container.

check [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/aspect-ratio/) for more details.

Comment: aspect-ratio doesn't work in old browsers on my phone for example don't work. but good idea!

Comment: Browser support is not a problem, but unfortunately it doesn't work: https://play.tailwindcss.com/3cAOSvwPFk

Answer (score 1):

To expand on existing answers, you're setting a fixed width on it, but you need to think about the dimensions of this element in terms of *aspect ratio*, which in your case is `1:1`. One way to define it is using Tailwind's [utilities for the `aspect-ratio` property](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/aspect-ratio). You need to make sure to propagate `h-full` all the way to your element so that finally setting `h-full` on that element has any effect.

The actual changes you need to make is:

1. add `h-full` to the Flex container that's wrapping the 2nd close button, this will give effect to the `h-full` on that button
2. remove `w-16` from both close buttons, because you want the width to depend on the height
3. instead add `aspect-square`, which will make width the same as height

If [`aspect-ratio`'s browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=aspect-ratio) isn't acceptable to you, the alternative is to use the [padding hack](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) provided by the [`@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio`](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-aspect-ratio) plugin.

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately it isn't working: https://play.tailwindcss.com/cSNCIm0nUX

Comment: You're missing `h-full` in that 2nd button.

Comment: Correct.  But now the icon is shrinking too much: https://play.tailwindcss.com/c4J2WChksz Is there a way to let it have the height like in the playground of my previous comment?

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot to mention that you won't like the result  However, that's a separate (and expected) problem caused by the SVG image shrinking. What you seem to be asking is to only decrease the icon's container (button), but keep the icon the same size, which you can do by removing `p-2`, but this entire effort significantly decreases the clickable area of the button. I would instead probably remove the `max-h-full` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fixed values, you could use "100%" for `height and width` and use fixed pixel values for `max-height` and `max-width`. That way the child won't get larger than the parent, but also not larger than the max-values define.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working: https://play.tailwindcss.com/0k2PHSox9K